# localName versus qName in SAX

Tags: xml, xml-parsing, sax

When using SAX to parse an XML file in Java, what is the difference between the parameters `localName` and `qName` in SAX methods such as

```
startElement(String uri, String localName, String qName, Attributes attributes)
```

Sometimes I can get a value from `localName`, but I get nothing from it now.
One SAXParserFactory's revision is 884950; the other's is 1.5.  I don't use namespace at all.  Does it matter?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it very much matters whether you're using namespaces and, specifically, how SAX is configured to use them...

### XML Name Terminology

[**qName**](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml-names/#NT-QName) is the full, [*qualified name*](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml-names/#dt-qualname), including both the [*namespace prefix*](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml-names/#dt-prefix), if any, and the [**localName**](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml-names/#dt-localname).

So, for `abc:xyz`

- The **namespace prefix** is `abc`.
- The **localName** is `xyz`.
- The **qName** is `abc:xyz`.

### SAX Configuration

There are two key features to configure for namespace processing:

1. `http://xml.org/sax/features/namespaces` (*namespaces*)
2. `http://xml.org/sax/features/namespace-prefixes` (*namespace-prefixes*)

Their settings will affect the values reported to `startElement` via *uri*, *localName*, and *qName*,

```
public void startElement (String uri, String localName,
                          String qName, Attributes atts)
  throws SAXException;
```

in combinations that might differ from your expectations.  Consider the following [examples](http://www.saxproject.org/namespaces.html):

> **Configuration Example**
>
> Consider the following simple sample document:
>
> ```
> <?xml version="1.0"?>
> <h:hello xmlns:h="http://www.greeting.com/ns/"
>          id="a1" h:person="David"/>
> ```
>
> If *namespaces* is true and *namespace-prefixes* is false (the
>   default), then a SAX2 XML reader will report the following:
>
> - an element with the Namespace URI "http://www.greeting.com/ns/" and    the localName "hello";
> - an attribute with no Namespace URI (empty string) and the qName (and    usually localName) "id"; and
> - an attribute with the Namespace URI "http://www.greeting.com/ns/" and    the localName "person".
>
> If *namespaces* is true and *namespace-prefixes* is true, then a SAX2
>   XML reader will report the following:
>
> - an element with the Namespace URI "http://www.greeting.com/ns/", the    localName "hello", and the qName "h:hello";
> - an attribute with no Namespace URI (empty string), no localName    (empty string), and the qName "xmlns:h";
> - an attribute with no Namespace URI (empty string), and the qName (and    usually localName) "id"; and
> - an attribute with the Namespace URI "http://www.greeting.com/ns/",    the localName "person", and the qName "h:person".
>
> If *namespaces* is false and *namespace-prefixes* is true, then a SAX2
>   XML reader will report the following:
>
> - an element with the qName "h:hello";
> - an attribute with the qName "xmlns:h";
> - an attribute with the qName "id"; and
> - an attribute with the qName "h:person".
>
> Note that when SAX2 reports namespace declaration attributes, like
>   "xmlns:h", it conforms to the *Namespaces in XML* recommendation from
>   W3C: they aren't in any namespace. Some other W3C specifications
>   violate that specification, and put such declarations into a
>   http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns/ namespace. If you're working with
>   namespace declarations, you may need to be aware of that issue.

Comment: Another couple of observations on this. (1) When the namespace-prefixes property is false, the parser isn't required to report the qName, but all known parsers do so. (2) It's particularly problematic to write a ContentHandler that accepts input from an arbitrary XMLReader that isn't under your control, because you have no way of discovering what the settings of `namespaces` and `namespace-prefixes` are. This is when it's useful to know about (1), because otherwise it's really hard to cater for all combinations.